# how to join multiple tables and sort the result as a json like format

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, right-join

I'm super new to mysql and I'm pretty sure this question might seem too elementary for some and I'm sorry about that

I have 3 tables: Portfolio, PortfolioFiles and PortfolioImages. The table Portfolio has one-to-many relationship with PortfolioFiles and PortfolioImages

What i need to do is to first get the list of last 10 Portfolios by date as well as their files and images.
I tried `RIGHT JOIN` and it works but I am facing multiple problems

1. When I sort set `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` it's only fetching 1 or 2 Portfolios because some Portfolios have multiple image and files in aforementioned tables so I don't know how to do that right
2. when i get the results they are all rows. I started working with noSQL databases like mongo and firebase so this SQL databases look mystery to me. So i would appreciate if someone could point out how i can query in a way that i don't have to sort out the fetched result

Table Portfolio

```
id                // primary key
uid               // foreign key reference User(id)
title
content
createdAt
```

Table PortfolioFiles

```
id               // primary key
uid              // foreign key references User(id) 
portfolioId      // foreign key references Portfolio(id) 
url 
createdAt
```

Table PortfolioImages

```
id               // primary key
uid              // foreign key references User(id)
portfolioId      // foreign key references Portfolio(id)
url
createdAt
```

This is what I did:

```
            SELECT 
                Portfolio.*, 
                PortfolioFiles.* , 
                PortfolioImages.* 
            FROM 
                Portfolio
            RIGHT JOIN 
                (PortfolioFiles, PortfolioImages)
            ON 
                PortfolioFiles.portfolioId=Portfolio.id 
            AND 
                PortfolioImages.portfolioId=Portfolio.id
            WHERE 
                Portfolio.uid = 49
            ORDER BY 
                Portfolio.createdAt DESC
```

**UPDATE:** ADDED SAMPLE DATA

this is how i want my output to be like:

```
            {
                "id": 52,
                "uid": 49,
                "title": "hey this is new title",
                "content":"this is my content",
                "createdAt": "2020-09-08 17:34:23",
                "files": [{
                        "id": 12,
                        "portfolioId": 52,
                        "uid": 49,
                        "url": "some random file url",
                        "createdAt": "2020-09-08 17:34:23"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "portfolioId": 52,
                        "uid": 49,
                        "url": "some random file url",
                        "createdAt": "2020-09-08 17:34:23"
                    },],
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": 44,
                        "portfolioId": 52,
                        "uid": 49,
                        "url": "some random file url",
                        "createdAt": "2020-09-08 17:34:23"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 45,
                        "portfolioId": 52,
                        "uid": 49,
                        "url": "some random image url",
                        "createdAt": "2020-09-08 17:34:23"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 46,
                        "portfolioId": 52,
                        "uid": 49,
                        "url": "some random file url",
                        "createdAt": "2020-09-08 17:34:23"
                    },
                ]
            }
```

this is the current result:

```
id|uid|       title        |       content    |    createdAt     |id|pid|uid|     url           |     createdAt    |id|pid|uid|      url           |    createdAt                                                                
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|    
|52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
|52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
|52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
|52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
|52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|12|52|49|some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is the data in the DB
PortfolioImages table

```
     id|portfolioId|uid|       url           |     createdAt     |
     ------------------------------------------------------------
    |44|     52    |49 |some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
    |45|     52    |49 |some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
    |46|     52    |49 |some random image url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
     ------------------------------------------------------------
```

PortfolioFiles table

```
     id|portfolioId|uid|       url           |     createdAt     |
     ------------------------------------------------------------
    |16|     52    |49 | some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
    |12|     52    |49 | some random file url|2020-09-08 17:34:23|
     ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Portfolio table

```
      id|uid|       title        |       content    |    createdAt     
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
  |52|49|hey this is new title|this is my content|2020-09-08 17:34:23
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Besides, your RIGHT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result anyway. Move the Portfolio.uid condition from WHERE to ON to get true RIGHT JOIN result.

Comment: Your structure is wrong. The portfolio may refer to one `uid` value whereas file/image may refer to another `uid`. Remove `uid` from files/images tables.

Comment: *get the list of last 10 Portfolios by date as well as their files and images* ALL files and images? Anycase show desired output (for a portfolio which have 2 files and 2 images and for a portfolio which have no file or/and image).

Comment: *This is what I did* Your query contradicts the structure - `Portfolio` is on the "one" side and hence LEFT JOIN must be used.

Comment: @jarlh i'm getting the same result even after moving WHERE to ON

Comment: @Akina still getting the same result with left join

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result, and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: @jahl added sample data and the results, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The query you are trying to write is:

```
SELECT p.*, pf.*, pi.* 
FROM Portfolio p LEFT JOIN
     PortfolioFiles pf
     ON pf.portfolioId = p.id LEFT JOIN
     PortfolioImages pi
     ON pi.portfolioId = p.id
WHERE p.uid = 49
ORDER BY p.createdAt DESC ;
```

I don't think this is what you *really* want, because this produces a Cartesian product between the files and images for a given portfolio.  So, if there are 4 files and 3 images, you get 12 rows. Well, actually, you would get 10 rows with a `LIMIT`.

However, your question is not clear on what results actually want.  I would advise you to ask a new question -- but a bit simpler.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want suffices.  A DB Fiddle is also appreciated.